# Setting up a website on a Virtual Private Server

Tags: linux, dns, centos, nameservers

I've got my website files on a VPS as of right now, I can access the website using the IP of my VPS, but despite my multiple attempts I can't successfully point my domain to my VPS. I've created a DNS through my registrar to point to the VPS IP, once I link it to my domain, accessing the domain results in a connection timeout. I've also tried using the free DNS services provided by no-ip, same issue. Could this be an issue with my domain services? It's very irritating, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might want to check that your DNS is actually setup correctly.  From a different computer, use nslookup to do a DNS lookup like so:

```
nslookup hostname.domain.tld
```

Does it return the correct address for your VPS?  If so, that's a good sign - the FQDN that you are using for your site is resolving correctly.

If the DNS is resolving correctly, then the next step to troubleshoot would be to see if your web server is responding to HTTP requests, by using telnet to attempt a connection to your web server on port 80.  The following blog has a good write-up about how to do this:  http://blog.tonycode.com/tech-stuff/http-notes/making-http-requests-via-telnet

Once you've isolated the problem to either a DNS issue or a webserver issue, you can troubleshoot further.  If you post your results to these tests here, someone here will be able to suggest the next steps.

Comment: Okay, the IP address is not returning the correct address, where do we go from here? Entering the DNS in the browser is no longer accessing the site either.

Comment: Then it means your DNS is not setup correctly.  I'm not sure which provider you are using to host your DNS, but they probably have a control panel that you can use to create DNS records.  Either you're doing something wrong in the control panel, or the provider is having some other issue.  If you want to post the FQDN of your site (e.g. hostname.domain.tld), I can tell you what I'm seeing.

Comment: My provider is Register.com, ns1.ambience639.com.

Comment: That looks like the name of your nameserver.  But, what is the fully qualified domain name of the site that you are trying to setup?  It should be something like www.yoursite.com.

Comment: www.ambience639.com
-Edit:
I tried setting it up on the vps using bind, if that helps at all.

Comment: OK.  Your whois record for ambience639.com is showing NS1.AMBIENCE639.COM and NS2.AMBIENCE639.COM for the name servers.  But NS1.AMBIENCE639.COM and NS2.AMBIENCE639.COM do not resolve.  That's your problem.  Your VPS provider probably provides DNS hosting as well - If so, you can login to your register.com account and change your nameservers for ambience639.com to those provided by your VPS provider.  Then, using the DNS control panel provided by your VPS provider, create an A record www.ambience639.com that points to the IP address of your web server, and that should solve your DNS problems.

Comment: This was the solution, we attempted using our own nameservers instead of the ones provided by Register.com without realizing. We kinda just took a shot in the dark and hoped for the best. Thanks a bunch though it really helped! Our site's functional now :)